# MySQL root password getting reset

Tags: mysql, passwords, root, reset

On my remote database server, the providers pre-installed MySQL server 5.1.68. I changed the root password by logging in mysql and  issuing these commands:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After changing password, I logged out and was able to log in again using the new password.

I noticed that it is sporadically being unset. To clarify, I can access the mysql server by directly again with:

```
$ mysql -u root
```

I have set a password on root many times, and I would like to resolve the problem.

Here are the users on the host:

```
mysql> SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
+----------------+--------------------+
| User           | Host               |
+----------------+--------------------+
| root           | 127.0.0.1          |
| fsl            | 128.104.xxx.xx     |
| fsl            | 128.104.xxx.xx     |
| rvadmin_public | 67.228.xxx.xx      |
| cphulkd        | localhost          |
| cpldap         | localhost          |
| datahandler    | localhost          |
| eximstats      | localhost          |
| horde          | localhost          |
| leechprotect   | localhost          |
| logaholic      | localhost          |
| root           | localhost          |
| roundcube      | localhost          |
| rvadmin        | localhost          |
| rvadmin_public | localhost          |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Is your data still there or does it get reset as well?

Comment: Are you issuing this command from your local machine, or some sort of SSH connection?

Comment: @PrashantSaxena Since in mysql the actual data is stored somewhere else than the settings files it could be that your provider resets the MySQL settings by simply compying over a standard image file. I had that once with a computer, all set up nicely, restarted and an image got copied all over - everything was lost.

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise: Yes, I am ssh'ing into the machine and then issuing these commands, could that be an issue? It appears that password is applicable for some session.

Comment: @Sebastian: Possible but why should the providers interfere with my server unless I ask them to

Comment: @PrashantSaxena: Is the mysql database locked down to local access only?  In that case, the provider is probably forcing it to use default username/password, thinking that since it's locked down to the local machine it's ok.

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise: I don't think that's the case, because they provided me with a non null password for root account which I later changed. Had that been the case, I should be able to login using old password

Comment: The main question is: does it work with `mysql --no-defaults` ? `.ini` files may be updated...

Comment: What is the output of this command:  SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user; ?

Comment: @Wrikken: I will have to wait for the problem to re-occur. Currently the password is working. I will try once the password is reset again

Comment: @Tucker: I have updated the problem statement with the output.

Comment: @Wrikken: Ok so password is reset again, what exact command should I use to login? mysql -u root --no-defaults? Thanks.

Comment: @PrashantSaxena Yep, try that one (and possibly inspect `mysql --print-defaults`).